# Zorin OS: Low disk space message

Tags: disk-usage, zorin

I am frequently getting low disk space error and attached screen displayed.

Let me know what to do.

Comment: without the OS, you are using, we cant do anything!

Comment: @utkash i am using zorin os 7

Comment: Where is the attached screen? Do you have a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete downloaded packages (.deb) already installed (and no longer needed)

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

To remove all stored archives in your cache for packages that can not be downloaded anymore (thus packages that are no longer in the repository or that have a newer version in the repository).

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

To remove unnecessary packages (After uninstalling an app there could be packages you don't need anymore)

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To delete old kernel versions

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-image-X.X.XX-XX-generic
```

If you don't know which kernel version to remove

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
```

Comment: OMG! 1432MB DISK SPACE CREATED

Comment: i dont have any other kernel so, that is useless. but the first 3 commands help me a lot!!!!~ you are great man!!!!

Comment: try to run these commands monthly

Comment: ok friend...thnx